# I would like to display the children of GridView according to the size of the child widget, but it will be expanded to the maximum width

Tags: flutter, dart

When creating a GridView like this, the size of the child widget is ignored and the child widget is expanded to fill the width.
However, I want to arrange it according to the size of the child widget, but how can I arrange it according to the size of the child widget?

```dart
          GridView.count(
            controller: controller,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 10,
                height: 10,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 10,
                height: 10,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need the dimensions of the child inside the grid view to be mentioned means you should use

```
return GridView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 28, right: 18, top: 22),
        itemCount: 2,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
          maxCrossAxisExtent: 100.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 1.0,
                  )));
        });
  }
```

Comment: Does that mean there is no point in specifying the size of the child widget?

Comment: Yes,  **maxCrossAxisExtent** will take care of that!

Comment: I see. It seems better to use Wrap instead of GridView

Comment: May be, on the point that you need different size for every child inside the grid means go for that, @sub